# What is the last physics paper or book written in Latin?

Tags: physics, language

What is the last physics paper or book written in Latin? I know Carl Neumann, for example, wrote papers in Latin in the 19th century. Are there any more recently than that?

Comment: For some noted scientific books, Wikipedia has a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Latin#Scientific_works.  I think mathematicians continued with Latin well after it was abandoned by physicists.  To verify this one would have to scour the national journals of the 19th century.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a modern mathematical paper in Latin,
http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~schechtman/defin-nova-preprint.pdf

Not sure about physicists:-)

Comment: Is there any reason why someone would still do this ?

Comment: Just for fun, I suppose. Beautiful language. Euler and newton wrote in it.

Comment: Yeah I guess this a good reason

Answer (score 5):

Dissertations in The Netherlands were traditionally written in Latin, until the second half of the 19th century. At Leiden University the last physics thesis in Latin is from 1854, [De galvanometra differentiali](http://ilorentz.org/history/proefschriften/sources/Bosscha_1854.pdf) by [Johannes Bosscha.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Bosscha)

Comment: [Seeger's 1864 dissertation](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6344) is in Latin.

Comment: but that's not from Leiden, is it?

Comment: No, it's from Göttingen.